# How to fix loose Accuride loose kitchen drawers?

Tags: drawers

How to fix Accuride loose drawers?

[image]

Comment: In order for you to receive and informed answer you need to provide and informed question. Please explain in detail  how they are malfunctioning.

Comment: Loose is very subjective. please provide some more information so that we can understand better what you are experiencing and what you want to experience. Also, is it all the drawers, or just the one?